# Merge two tables with common values by adding the count, append rest

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, created at runtime, which pulls some data from some entirely different tables and joins and complex where clauses, and finally, I have these two tables with columns something like this:

**TableCars:**

````````````````````````
Id    Company    Views
```````````````````````
01    Honda        12
32    audi         6
18    BMW          3
17    Vector       5
````````````````````````

**TableBikes:**

````````````````````````
Id    Company    Views
```````````````````````
01    Honda        3
32    audi         1
19    Kawasaki     2
````````````````````````

**Note:**
company names and id's will always be the same in these two tables, like, `honda = 01`

I want to merge these two tables in the sense that I dont want any repetitions in the names (or id's) and I want the views to be added. Is there any way to do this without using a while loop and a whole lotta hair loss?

the resultant table should be something like this:

**ResultantTable**

```````````````````````
Id    Company    Views
``````````````````````
01    Honda        15
32    audi         7
18    BMW          3
17    Vector       5
19    Kawasaki     2
```````````````````````

Many thanks in advance.

<sub>ps: I tried to check google, came across "merge" clause, looked up on that, MSDN was way over my head. I never understand ANYTHING in MSDN. wonder if there are any other people like me.</sub>

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a new table, or just trying to select the combined data?

Comment: @womp I need to merge them into a new table, so I can filter the result again, on some other parameters and then return the result set. Adding them into a new table will definitely make it easier for further processing. thanks.

Comment: I am not actually trying to create a permanent table, just a temporary runtime table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

`SELECT company, SUM(views) FROM 
(SELECT company, views FROM first
UNION ALL
SELECT company, views FROM second) as t
GROUP BY company`

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Great, this works, thanks so much! I had to have the ``as t``. I was trying to accommodate this with the merge statement!

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, company, sum(views) views
from
(
select id, company, views
from tablecars
union all
select id, company, views
from tablebikes
) joined
group by id, company
```

You can always turn SELECT statements into a CREATE table statement:

```
select id, company, sum(views) views
into NewTableName
from
(
select id, company, views
from tablecars
union all
select id, company, views
from tablebikes
) joined
group by id, company
```

I don't normally recommended this method to create permanent tables.  It is better to create the table and manually define keys, constraints, defaults, indexes.  If you create it this way, you can still add required keys later using ALTER table statements.

If you will always have the two base tables around, and you need this "joined" data for querying/reporting, **and** it has to keep in sync with the base tables - then what you are really after is a VIEW using the first SELECT statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, but its marking all my fields after the first line of select in red. cant understand why though.

Comment: Hi, I found out why it didn't work out, like in the first answer, I had to have a ``as t`` for it to work, but thanks for the explanation, really helped.

Comment: but it is sql server is underling everything in the first select line, plust everything else after joined, so I tried the other answer. sorry!